# call to public variables to via object

Tags: php, function, object, constructor, pdo

`$sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->menu);` i want to call to the db table dynamically.in here it was selecting only the menu.i want to call it from object ???

```
 <?php

    $dbhost=null;
    $dbname=null;
    $dbuser=null;
    $dbpass=null;

    $file = __DIR__ ."/config.json";

    $array = file_get_contents($file);
    $dbConfig=json_decode($array);

    $pardConfig=new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbConfig[0].';'.'dbname='.$dbConfig[1],$dbConfig[2],$dbConfig[3]);

    class pardDb
    {
        public $config = "pard_admin_config";
        public $article = "pard_article";
        public $menu = "pard_menu";
        public $user = "pard_user";
        public $images = "pard_images";

        function pardTemplate($pardConfig,$pardDbTable){
            $sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->menu);
            $sql->execute();
            $result=$sql->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
            $item = array_reverse($result);
            return $item;
        }
    }

    $pardDbTable = new pardDb();
    $pardDbTable->pardTemplate($config,$pardConfig);

    ?>
```

I want one object and need to call it like this ?

```
    echo $obj->menu; 
echo $obj->article;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try refactory this in one designe patterns (start your studing by Active Record and Data Mapper) add inheritance:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

after see the Magic Methods __get and __set

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get